# issue using gradle in an android project

Tags: java, android, gradle

I almost know nothing form `Android`, I created a project and then I wanted to use some plugin based on `Gradle`, so I added some `build.gradle` file. I added there

```
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    mavenCentral()
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:library:+'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion '18'

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}
```

The doc says `import uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshLayout;` to `private PullToRefreshLayout mPullToRefreshLayout;` But, this package can not be resolved. Someone can help ?

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
dependencies {
    mavenCentral()
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:library:+'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

To this:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:library:+'
}
```

Comment: I made the change, but I still get an error. In fact I am not familiar to `Gradle`, am I suppose to run the project in a specific way. Because, how does the project downloads the remote plugin ?

Comment: You should synchronise Android Studio with gradle first. Read more about gradle usage on blogs